# Proper approach to hang a Python program

Tags: python, linux

There is a Python script which calls a library `selenium`, which calls on a server binary `chromedriver`, then hangs and waits for connections. It looks like:

```
... connect selenium ...

# Hang
while True:
    pass
```

The script can not exit since if it does, `chromedriver` also exits, while certain other programs need it.

It works fine, except that much CPU time is spent, constant 25% on my machine (Ubuntu). Therefore it seems that `while True: pass` is unacceptable. What's the proper approach for this?

Comment: I guess this is asked before but I can't find one. Thanks in advance for duplicate suggestions.

Comment: I guess you need to use `async/await`

Comment: @pavel Thanks for the suggestion, I am not familiar with that. I will read the doc for it.

Comment: Well, that is the proper way to handle waiting for i/o. See more here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html

Comment: @pavel. He's not waiting for the I/O. Just waiting.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, but he is waiting for connections from `selenium`.

Comment: @pavel. OK. I'll leave it to you to find an appropriate duplicate then. I am sure there are many, but this is not my area of expertise.

Comment: @pavel Thank you, I wrap my code with asyncio and it works great! Will you turn your comment into an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: @pavel I turn the original `while True: pass` into a `while True: await asyncio.sleep(1000)` and it just works.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Thanks for the hint! Without that I would have buried myself in selenium documents.

Comment: @user26742873. You don't need asyncio for that: just plain time.sleep will work great.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Will you turn your comment into an answer? I tested and plain `while True: time.sleep(1000)` just works - that should be the answer, thanks for telling me.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Oops, I should have taken a look into the edit history for that.